# move_uploaded_file failed to open stream: Permission denied - Mac

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload, xampp

While i am trying to move_uploaded_file in php with following code :

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload2']['tmp_name'])){

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload2']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['fileupload2']['name']);

    }
```

I've got this error saying:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/VIDEO_TS.VOB): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Week3/Lesson2/do_upload.php on line 24
```

i tried in the terminal and didn't work:

```
sudo CHMOD 775 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Week3/Lesson2/do_upload.php 

sudo chmod -R 0755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Week3/Lesson2/do_upload.php 

sudo chown nobody /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Week3/Lesson2/do_upload.php
```

I am still getting the error and i am using Yosemite, any other solution ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My solution was to give the permission for the images folder and the php file, by going to the file > Right click > Get info > and then change all the permissions to `read&write` as the following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am using ubuntu and once I have encounter this problem, I have solved this problem by changing all the access permissions of the folder in which I want to move the files to 'create and delete files'. See below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the same permission for your target(uploading) folder

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by changing permission as described avobe
and making the target folder in the same directory {Root rather than Home } in which application is running

path for image upload

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emp/files/admin_assets/addsdassets/targrt_Folder
```

path of folder in which application is running

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emp/files/admin_assets/addsdassets/inser_db.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try after changing owner for the folder images where you are saving the images. It may work.

```
chown ownername:group folder;
```

you have to give absolute address of the folder

Answer (score 0):

I was running Yii2 on IIS (Windows 10) and I tweaked the path and got it working. See code snippet below:

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    $model->image = $image->getBaseName().'.'.$image->extension;            
    if($model->save()) {
        $image->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->image);//Notice the path change here
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
    }

}
else {

    return $this->render('update-image', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by restricted permission. To resolve extend or change your permission to the folder using: `chmod -R 777 folder-path`.

E.g:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/aitech/images/passport_photos
```

Answer (score -3):

apply

```
sudo chmod 777 images/
```

to the folder/directory which is your server folder to store images. Please check which is your folder. Totally depends on your choice.

Comment: Oh yay, a `chmod 777` "solution". Usually insecure, hardly ever necessary, sometimes expedient as a quick hack.