# Get bytes transferred using PHP5 for POST request

Tags: javascript, php, post, http-post

**Note** I am new to PHP, Apache and programming for servers so more thorough explanations will be appreciated.

---

#### Context

I created - in javascript - a progress bar to display when a file is uploaded. Current I have the progress bar update at a set frame-rate (to see if it works).

Clearly to make this an accurate progress bar, everything should in relation to the number of bytes transferred in comparison to the total number of bytes.

#### Question

using PHP5 how can I get information regarding the number of bytes transferred in relation to the total number of bytes of the file, such that I can pass that to a JS function `updateProgress(bytesSoFar, totalBytes)` to update my progress bar? Please verbosely walk me through the modifications needed to the code below to get this to work. I have seen `xhr` examples, but they are not thoroughly accessible.

I have just set up [LocalHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455270/setting-up-localhost-server-for-macos-sierra-to-use-php-and-apache) and am using W3Schools' [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) tutorial. To get the simulated ''upload'' to work, I changed the local permissions as suggested in this S.O. [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915957/move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-mac). I don't necessarily need to read the file, I just want to know many bytes have been transferred.

---

## Code

Currently I have two files:

- index.php
- upload.php

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

## Update

I have found this code:

#### test.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {



  // move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Upload Progress Bar</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #bar_blank {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    }

    #bar_color {
    background-color: #006666;
    height: 20px;
    width: 0px;
    }

    #bar_blank, #hidden_iframe {
    display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="bar_blank">
    <div id="bar_color"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="status"></div>

  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden_iframe">
    <input type="hidden" value="myForm" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
    <input type="file" name="userfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Start Upload">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleBarVisibility() {
      var e = document.getElementById("bar_blank");
      e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }

    function createRequestObject() {
      var http;
      if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      else {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return http;
    }

    function sendRequest() {
      var http = createRequestObject();
      http.open("GET", "progress.php");
      http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http); };
      http.send(null);
    }

    function handleResponse(http) {
      var response;
      if (http.readyState == 4) {
        response = http.responseText;

        document.getElementById("bar_color").style.width = response + "%";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response + "%";

        if (response < 100) {
          setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
        }
        else {
          toggleBarVisibility();
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done.";
        }
      }
    }

    function startUpload() {
      toggleBarVisibility();
      setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
    }

    (function () {
      document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = startUpload;
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### progress.php

```
session_start();

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "myForm";
if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
  $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
  $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
  echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;

  $message = ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;

  $message = "$message"
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
else {
  echo 100;
}
?>
```

Which, like my previous code, transfers the file. However, this doesn't show the bytes until the end (even though it should alert for that), also it opens a new window with the "Done." statement in the previous window.

Comment: Even though this question is probably a duplicate, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3694435/294696
You can monitor upload progress using only javascript.

Comment: Yea, I saw that, but it uses JS....

Comment: @SumNeuron See also [How to read and echo file size of uploaded file being written at server in real time without blocking at both server and client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475492/how-to-read-and-echo-file-size-of-uploaded-file-being-written-at-server-in-real)

Comment: can you provide `phpinfo()` for you localhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this [Php File Upload Progress Bar](http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/) that may help you get started in case you insist on using Php to display progress. This uses the PECL extension [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to get uploaded file progress details. It is possible to calculate the number of bytes received by the server using the response of 
**`apc_fetch()`** as per the first link.

Another interesting [Track Upload Progress](https://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/) tutorial that uses Php's native [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) feature.

Lastly, if you are a little open to using Javascript (or a JS library), that would be **ideal**. An easy to use, easy to setup, well known and a maintained library that I know of is [FineUploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader)

Comment: Hey thank you for the links, but I specified in the bounty that I was looking for a *detailed* explanation of how your chosen method works. Your first link doesn't display a progress bar (and looking at the code seems to just use an interval timer rather than getting the bytes). The third links states `PHP may see the file upload only once fully uploaded` (as I have already pointed out), the fourth seems useful - but its documentation is convolution - and is outside the scope of PHP. The second link shares the flaws of the third.

Comment: Updated the answer. Also, answering your comments, yes, it does use a timer (every 500ms to ping the server and get the uploaded file details upto that instant) The provided link does work, try uploading a rather larger file to see the progress bar. If you choose to upload smaller files, reduce the timer interval to ensure your progress bar is updated accordingly.

Comment: `PHP may see the file upload only once fully uploaded` Looks like you missed the previous half of the sentence. It says that `The web server's request buffering has to be disabled otherwise PHP may see the  ....`  If you choose to use this option, you should disable request buffering. And lastly, regarding FineUploader's [documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/) and [examples](https://fineuploader.com/demos) I think they're certainly pretty straightforward to understand. (but as already stated in the answer, that's a JS based solution) IMHO, it is better to use JS for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) feature. It's native but require some php.ini configuration.

Please, take a look at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

**UPDATE 1**

Note, you don't need to change your upload.php. You can create a new php file (ex. progress.php) and make requests to them to check the upload progress with your JS.

**progress.php**

```
<?php
$upload_id = $_GET['upload_id];
print json_encode($_SESSION['upload_progress_'.$upload_id]);
```

Then your JS will make a GET request to `progress.php?upload_id=YourIdValue` and you will receive a JSON with all progress information.

Comment: So thanks for bring this to my attention. A couple of things: the links are identical; it states on clearly on that page that the method you provided states that it may not be able to get that information until after the upload is complete; and there is no complete example.

Comment: I don't know if you were notified that I updated my answer to give you more information. If not, please take a look again.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. If I make an independent file, then that code would never be called. So even if the above code did work, it wouldnt in context.

Comment: PHP store and update all upload progress information at the SESSION variable. All magic occur when you set `<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123" />` at the form. If PHP receive this information, it will pass all upload info to this session variable. When you have a session defined, it will be available for all requests until the session end or you destroy it. If you want, take a look at [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) documentation to understand a little bit more.